# How to reload/refresh Main Activity from BroadcastReceiver class outside MainActivity - Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have a MainActivity class that calls a server to fetch messages in the onCreate() method.

Then I have a BroadcastReceiver class outside the MainActivity class.

This is my BroadcastReceiver class:

```
  public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {

        // This is where I want to refresh/reload MainActivity 

    }

}
```

}

If extras != null I want to refresh my MainActivity class so that it does the onCreate() call again. How can I do this?

This is my manifest file snippet:

```
  <receiver
    android:name="za.co.vine.samplepush.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>

        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

        <category android:name="za.co.vine.samplepush" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: start MainActivity using intent

Comment: use a second broadcast receiver or a localbroadcast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an intent to launch the `MainActivity` and I'd change the android:launchMode attribute to "singleTop" so that you don't have 2 instances of you MainActivity

Comment: How do i call that from the BroadcastReceiver class that sits outside the MainActivity class?

Comment: madhu's answer is probably good then. I'd change the android:launchMode attribute to "singleTop" so that you don't have 2 instances of you MainActivity

Comment: Thank you very much! Add it as an answer or edit the above and I will accept it?